# Navigation Controller inside Tab bar Controller not showing title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on a cocoa touch framework. In my framework I have a view contoller and a tab bar controller with different tabs. I am integrating framework in another iOS project.

Now that iOS project has a navigation controller with a splash screen and another navigation controller with a login screen. So the view hierarchy is like this:

Navigation Controller -> Splash Screen -> Navigation Controller -> Login Screen

In the project, when Login Controller is pushed the rootview controller becomes the navigation controller of Login Screen

```
let hkWindow = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    hkWindow.window!.rootViewController = self.navigationController
```

Now the problem is when I comment the code above in Login Screen, my navigation titles inside tab bar controllers work absolutely fine but with the above code my navigation item shows nothing, not even a back button on push view controllers.

When I coment the code my navigation bar shows absolutely perfect

[image: When I coment the code my navigation bar shows absolutely perfect]

When I uncomment the code, my navigation bar becomes blank

[image: When I uncomment the code, my navigation bar becomes blank]

Please help guys!

Comment: why do you have two navigation controller?

Comment: I am working for a third party vendor, they have 2 navigation controllers.

Comment: There isn't enough information here... are you setting the title within the LoginViewController? Where does the Tab Bar come into play?

Answer (score 0):

you can set title view manually, set in the tab bar controller

```
if let tabController = self.parent as? UITabBarController {
     tabController.navigationItem.title = "Transaction history"
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, title doesnt show. not even a back button after a push a view controller in navigation controller.